# Software to download part of an ASX stream

Tags: gratis, video, streaming

I have an .asx file that is continuously streaming video. I need to download a specified length of that stream so that I can process the data in another piece of software(matlab). The asx files is a stream of a traffic camera that you can access [here][1]. Here are some of my requirements:

- I would like it to run on Windows however if there is absolutely nothing for windows then I would be willing to use Linux.
- I would like the application to have either a command line interface or a minimal GUI.
- I would also like the application to be quite small in size *size in megabytes* < 50.
- The application should be free and if it is open source that is even better.

I have already looked at several programs such as streaming download project which is very old(greater than 10 years) and several paid programs which look to be quite expensive for what they do. I have also looked at VLC which did not work as it outputted a file that was 199 bytes and VLC also did not have an option for the duration that I wanted saved. Most of the software that I have already looked at also looks like it works on ASX files that link to specific clips not ASX files that continuously stream video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/):

- Free, gratis & opensource
- Cross platform including windows
- My windows install is 112MB twice what you are looking for but you could probably cut that down quite a bit.
- Command line interface
- Can capture from a URL or other stream
- You can specify how long a clip to grab
- Command line interface

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not realize ffmpeg could do this.

Comment: It is an amazing tool @AidenGrossman!

Comment: Could you also provide a sample command for ffmpeg that would download a section of the asx stream?